# Union vs Inheritance in python implementation

Tags: python, typing

Let's say we have this class.

```
class MyConfig():
   config_type : SomeEnum 
   retries: int
   context: Context
```

This Context depends on the value of type meaning the context is dependent on its value. Which implementation of Context is best?  why one is better than the other.

```
class MySpecificContext:
   value: int
   name: str

class OtherUnrelatedContext:
   length:int
    position: int

Contex = Union[MySpecificContex,OtherUnrelatedContext]
```

or

```
class Context:
   pass

class MySpecificContext(Context):
   value: int
   name: str

class OtherUnrelatedContext(Context):
   length:int
    position: int
```

To be more specific. Let say you have a configuration class, this configuration will hold data that will be used to configure a process. This process will contain a few things that relate to all configurations, like `retries` value. However, it is expected that based on `config_type` there is an additional context that is required. This is highly related to the particular configuration type. Note that these classes only hold data and they are not expected to implement any behaviors in the future. However, it is expected that the SomeEnum enumeration will be extended and more "contexts" will be added at some point. Think of my config as immutable.

Comment: Seems like you probably want to use a Generic type somewhere, but your example isn't detailed enough for me to figure out exactly what you're trying to do.  Is the config_type a type, or is it an actual Enum instance?  How does it relate to the Context?  It would help to see examples that ignore the typing problem for now and just show what sorts of values are expected in this config object -- that might make it possible to reverse-engineer the type annotations that match what your code is doing.

Comment: Does a given MyConfig object always have the same kind of Context, or can it switch around at runtime?

Comment: @Samwise MyConfig is thought as immutable

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I might approach it:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Generic, NamedTuple, TypeVar, Union


class MySpecificContext(NamedTuple):
    value: int
    name: str


class OtherUnrelatedContext(NamedTuple):
    length: int
    position: int


Context = Union[MySpecificContext, OtherUnrelatedContext]
_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=Context)


class SomeEnum(Enum):
    MY_SPECIFIC = 1
    OTHER_UNRELATED = 2


config_types = {
    MySpecificContext: SomeEnum.MY_SPECIFIC,
    OtherUnrelatedContext: SomeEnum.OTHER_UNRELATED,
}


class MyConfig(Generic[_T]):
    def __init__(self, context: _T, retries: int):
        self.retries = retries
        self.context = context

    @property
    def config_type(self) -> SomeEnum:
        return config_types[type(self.context)]
```

Encoding the kind of type relationship you're talking about between two attributes is tricky; I can't think of any way to do it without having different `MyConfig` subclasses.  On the other hand, if you can derive one from the other, it doesn't make sense to have them be independent attributes in the first place, which is why I've just turned `config_type` into a property that's derived from `config`.  (This is assuming you're wedded to this interface -- I would just get rid of the enum and the mapping and use the context type directly, so as to have less code to maintain.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I like your approach.

Comment: Not sure I understand the point of the enum or the property. `type(config.context)` should return `Type[_T]` which should be sufficient for reflection and even more useful in that it may be usable in `isinstance` checks.

Comment: As I said: *I would just get rid of the enum and the mapping and use the context type directly*

Answer (score 1):

They *can* be functionally equivalent, but there are a couple differences.

- With inheritance, the set of types can be extended by the user. With the union, only the enumerated types are allowable. There are benefits for both depending on what you are trying to accomplish.
- The inheritance approach requires you predict the common methods you wish to dynamically dispatch to and declare them in the base class. The union approach creates an interface ad-hoc based on the intersection of the methods of all the types in the type set.

  - The implicit interface is a double-edged sword as changes to the union may cause the interface to change, making existing correct code become incorrect; i.e. it's potentially fragile.
- With inheritance, all types in the set must be defined after the base type. This means you can't add an existing type to the type set. Unions do not have this problem.
- You can't use unions in `isinstance` checks until Python 3.10.

Based on your use case, I think unions would make more sense because:

1. You don't seem to need to allow the user to extend the type set.
2. You are not dynamically-dispatching to a common method of the types in the type set, you are always disambiguating before using.